# Any C++ RegExp library with support full regexp in lookbehind

Tags: library, c++, regex

For  example  symbol * and +. Like net.Framework C#.
This example should work sucessfully:

```
(?<=a.*)b
```

Comment: how about C++11 and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: @RichardChambers Where  it  support unlimited/unfixed lookbehind?

Comment: I have only used it fleetingly and am not well versed in its applications and support. If I had a definitive answer for you, I would have created an actual answer rather than a comment. I suggest that you update your question with a bit more info about the target environment, target compiler, etc. Also I suggest you take a look at the boost library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html and I  am not sure what "unlimited/unfixed lookbehind" is so I suggest you provide more idea as to your actual requirements rather than "full support RegExp" with an example.

Comment: So this forum thread http://www.website-watcher.info/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1522&view=next indicates that .NET is one of the best and you mention C# as well so I suggest you look at C++/CLI with Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.

Comment: License? Price? Source availability? Supported compilers? Operating systems?

Comment: @RichardChambers: C++11 regular expressions do not seem to include look-behind support. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex and the links to the syntax options: [Modified ECMAScript](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript), [Extended POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), grep and egrep.

Comment: I suppose C++11 RegEx does not, I will take your word for it. I was thinking that C++/CLI with .NET would be the way you would go since C++ and C# are almost the same so far as .NET though syntax is often different. See [Regular Expressions (C++/CLI) from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4384yce9.aspx) with documentation and examples that "demonstrate the use of the .NET Framework System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace".

Answer (score 1):

#### [The Perl-compatible regular expression library](https://www.pcre.org/) (PCRE)

- Language: C (seems to also have C++ wrappers)
- Compiler support: GCC for sure, probably all popular compilers
- Actively maintained: Yes, last release is from 3 months ago
- License: BSD

PCRE underpins the regular expression support in R, PHP, Delphi, MonetDB and other software projects - so it's pretty widely used.

[This page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) suggests that the PCRE library supports variable-length look-behind, albeit it doesn't support arbitrary regexes within look-behinds.

<sub>PS: The ([https://regular-expressions.info](https://regular-expressions.info/)) website is an interesting source of information about various regular expression engines/libraries.</sub>